# How to redirect the user to another webpage without using JavaScript in a Jinja2 HTML template?

Tags: python, html, redirect, jinja2, fastapi

I'm using a Jinja2 Template with FastAPI. All I want to know is how to implement a `redirect` action in Jinja2 template **without using JavaScrpit**?

If the variable I set exists, I would like to force a page redirection.

```
{% if my_var %}
    // What value should I enter here?
{% endif %}
```

Case in my titles with java :

```
<c:if test="${!emtpy(my_var)}">  
    <% response.sendRedirect("/new/url"); %>
</c:if>
```

Case in my PHP :

```
if(!empty($my_var) ){
    header('Location:/new/url');
    exit;  
}
```

If there is no way, I have to use JavaScript, but I don't want to use this method at all, as some of people deactivate JavaScript in their browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wouldn't like to use JavaScript, you may use a [`<meta>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) HTML element/tag with the [`http-equiv`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-http-equiv) attribute set to `refresh`. This instruction specifies:

> The **number of seconds** until the page should redirect to another - only if
> the `content` attribute contains a non-negative integer followed by the
> string `';url='`, and a valid URL.

Hence, the value in the `content` is the delay before the browser redirects the user to the new page. To redirect immediately, set this parameter to `0` seconds, as shown in the example below.

The `<meta>` tag should be placed inside a `<head>` element; however, in HTML 5 it is permitted to use `<meta>` tags inside a `<body>` tag  as well, [as long as there is an `itemprop` attribute present](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element).

### Example

```html
<head>
     {% if my_var %}
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='https://stackoverflow.com'" />
     {% endif %}
</head>
```